Two visas for France at the same time
I have a valid type C Schengen visa for France that I used and still have days in it. I had a job in France so I applied for a type D visa that I got. They did not revoke the other visa, is it normal ? Can I have problem with the immigration control ?

Yey, since they are 2 different types of visas this is normal.


Can I have problem with the immigration control?

Well, there's a small chance that immigration will see your valid tourist visa first and assume that's your only valid visa. If this happens, simply inform that you have a work visa also and the situation should resolve itself. I'd also answer the questions to the tune of "what is your purpose of visit" with "work, I have a work visa in there" until your tourist visa expires.
Previously when traveling with others (they were visitors, I was a resident) and approaching border officers together, I've had them start talking first and as a result the border staff thought I was a tourist too. I cleared things up and all was well.
Once you get your residence permit card from France (carte de séjour), you'll have to give that alongside your passport anyways, and at that point there will be no potential confusion.

Yes, it's fine. The two visas give you permissions to visit France for different purposes. Also the C visa is about to expire, so it would be a waste of effort for them to revoke it.
